# change wallpaper style using c#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

i am developing a basic winform application for which i want to change wallpaper using c#, **the problem the image is not stretched to fit the screen size.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace DailyWallpaper
{
    class WallpaperChanger
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern Int32 SystemParametersInfo(
            UInt32 action, UInt32 uParam, String vParam, UInt32 winIni);

        private static readonly UInt32 SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER = 0x14;
        private static readonly UInt32 SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE = 0x01;
        private static readonly UInt32 SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE = 0x02;

        public void SetWallpaper(String path)
        {
            SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, path, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
        }
    }
}
```

can anyone tell me how can i rectify this error, thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try executing the following code:

```
public void SetWallpaper(String path)
    {
        RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop", true);
        key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 2.ToString());
        key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 0.ToString());

        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, path, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
    }
```

---

EDIT:

You can also modify your function and pass a Style to it:

```
public void SetWallpaper(String path, Style style)
    {
        RegistryKey key = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Control Panel\Desktop", true);
        if (style == Style.Stretched)
        {
            key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 2.ToString());
            key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 0.ToString());
        }
        if (style == Style.Centered)
        {
            key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 1.ToString());
            key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 0.ToString());
        }
        if (style == Style.Tiled)
        {
            key.SetValue(@"WallpaperStyle", 1.ToString());
            key.SetValue(@"TileWallpaper", 1.ToString());
        }

        SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETDESKWALLPAPER, 0, path, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE | SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer

Comment: @SijoJose You are welcome! Let me know if that was what you needed :)

Comment: that's what i really wanted, thank you for the help.

Comment: @SijoJose If a post answers your question, click on the check mark next to it to accept it. You gain reputation by doing that.